# FinderException after upgrade to Jboss 7

Tags: hibernate-spatial, jboss

I am using hibernate to persist data. This was working in Jboss 5. Recently we upgraded to Jboss 7.
The jars used remain same i.e. hibernate3.jar, hibernate-spatial-1.1.jar, hibernate-spatial-oracle-1.1.jar

Now I am getting this error stack:

> 12:38:22,585 SEVERE [com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler] (http--0.0.0.0-10000-28) Problem finding Oracle Connection: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Problem finding Oracle Connection
>       at org.hibernatespatial.oracle.OracleJDBCTypeFactory.createStruct(OracleJDBCTypeFactory.java:38) [hibernate-spatial-oracle-1.1.jar:]
>       at org.hibernatespatial.oracle.SDOGeometry.store(SDOGeometry.java:154) [hibernate-spatial-oracle-1.1.jar:]
>       at org.hibernatespatial.oracle.SDOGeometryType.conv2DBGeometry(SDOGeometryType.java:82) [hibernate-spatial-oracle-1.1.jar:]
>       at org.hibernatespatial.oracle.SDOGeometryType.nullSafeSet(SDOGeometryType.java:72) [hibernate-spatial-oracle-1.1.jar:]
>       at org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType.nullSafeSet(GeometryUserType.java:201) [hibernate-spatial-1.1.jar:]
>       at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:140) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2431) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2875) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
>       at ............persistence.webservice.PersistenceHelper.persistLayers(PersistenceHelper.java:175) [classes:]

---

Steps taken to resolve:

1. Upgrading hibernate to 4.3 from 3.6 did not solve. Moreover lot of incompatibility issues.
2. Found somewhere to downgrade DBCP to 1.2.2 from 1.3 (which comes with Jboss 7 upgrade), so replaced commons-dbcp.jar at Root.war/WEBINF/lib with commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar. But no change in error.

=================================================

Found some suggestions at:
http://hibernate-spatial.1140993.n2.nabble.com/How-to-use-hibernate-spatial-with-Oracle-and-c3p0-td7572480.html

But found a mismatch with my code as I'm not using c3p0, so don't know how to plugin this fix.

================================================

My code block from error stack traced where this problem occurs and it is as follows:

```
                if(USER_ANNOTATION_LAYER.equalsIgnoreCase(persistenceDTO.getTableName())){
            UserAnnotationLayers userAnnotationLayers = persistenceDTO.getUserAnnotationLayers();

            if(userAnnotationLayers!=null){
                Geometry geom =getGeometryFromWKT(userAnnotationLayers.getLayer_location_wkt());
                geom.setSRID(4326);
                if(geom!=null)
                {
                    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                    session.beginTransaction();
                    UserAnnotationLayer userLayer = new UserAnnotationLayer();
                    userLayer.setUser_id(persistenceDTO.getUser_id());                      
                    ----------------------------------
                    ---------------------------------
                    userLayer.setUal_status("N");
                    session.save(userLayer);
                    session.getTransaction().commit();//place from stack where error occurs
                    layer_id = userLayer.getLayer_id();                     
                    persistenceDTO.getUserAnnotationLayers().setLayer_id(layer_id);                                             
                 }
```

==========================================================